# How do I modify the values of an iterator in Python?

Tags: python, iterator, python-itertools

As a side project, I'm making a basic HTML parser. The HTML comes in as a string, and I make an iterator for it. I need to remove groups of whitespace at certain points, e.g. if the character is whitespace, I'd like to consume it, remove it, and advance one by one until I hit a non-whitespace character, where the function would stop.

Iterator setup:

```
from more_itertools import peekable
chars = peekable("</        html    >")
```

For example:

```
"</        html    >
```

...becomes:

```
"</html    >"
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Just updated the post for more clarification, I forgot to mention I want it to remove whitespace from where it currently is until it reaches a non-whitespace character, where it would stop entirely.

Comment: There is no generic way to remove a character from an iterator, although here, you could just use `next(chars)` and then maybe `continue`? Or honestly, just use `filter`

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile then? Perhaps you could give some actual context, rather than assuring us this makes sense.

Comment: My bad, I'm new to this. I'll update the post with context.

Comment: Updated it for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

I think the [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) function is what you are looking for.

An example:

```py
import string
text = "</        html    >"

for c in filter(lambda x: x not in string.whitespace, text):
    print(c, end="")
```

The output is `</html>`

Comment: That's almost it, but I'd like to remove connected groups of whitespace individually. So, if the iterator is pointing at the whitespace after the slash, it would remove the whitespace until it hits the H, where it stops and doesn't remove any more whitespace until its called again.